# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL error when making connection between React and Nodejs (Nginx - digital ocean)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, digital-ocean

I’ve set up a Reactjs app, Nodejs backend server and Mysql database on the same droplet. I can visit the react site ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) without problems, and my backend is also running.

But I cannot connect frontend to backend, I always get “ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR” (on my local windows machine, everything is working perfectly).

It seems the backend server doesnt make a secure connection.
When I do ip_address:8800?api-command, I get a response. So, it is working. I connect from FE to BE in React like this:

```
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://ip_address_server:8800"
```

I have to admit, I never used Nginx before, but this is my config file:

```
server {        
    root /var/www/Site_Name.com/html/build;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name Site_Name.com;
location / {
                            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/Site_Name.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/Site_Name.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot}

server {
server_name nodejs.Site_Name.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8800; #whatever port your app runs on
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.Site_Name.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.Site_Name.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

Things I already tried: A subdomain has been created, SSL certificates have been installed for both domain and subdomain, listen 80 on nodejs server config, ....
What am I doing wrong? Is there something I missed? I hope someone can help me out or at least put me on the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server block for `server_name nodejs.Site_Name.com` listens on port `443` and proxy the request to your application on port `8800`. So you should be able to request your backend from the frontend with the url `https://nodejs.Site_name.com`.

```js
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://nodejs.Site_name.com"
```

Also you should change your nginx config for the proxy pass
`proxy_pass https://localhost:8800; #whatever port your app runs on`
to http:
`proxy_pass http://localhost:8800; #whatever port your app runs on`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you proposed but then I get this: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sitename.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://nodejs.sitename.com:8800/manuallogin?email=xxx'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Really stuck here :-(

Comment: Can you have a look if `http://nodejs.sitename.com:8800/manuallogin?email=xxx` is loaded via http? If so you should use https at that spot. Also why does it request `nodejs.sitename.com:8800`? I think you should leave the port out. Have you set the baseUrl exactly like above? Then im curious why it wants to request that url that is not at all the baseUrl.

Comment: thank you for helping me out ...
solution was indeed removing ':8800' from the baseUrl. Just using 'https://nodejs.sitname.com' works
thanks a lot!!!